# Do the ngfactory files themselves have to be compiled in Angular 2 AOT compilation?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-aot, angular-compiler-cli

Whenever I compile an Angular 2 application with `ngc`, it creates the `.ngfactory.ts` files for every component and then compiles all the typescript to javascript.

However, when I run ´ngc´ the first time, it creates the `ngfactory` files, but compiles only **other** files to javascript. This means no compiled `ngfactory` javascript files are produced.

On second run, it does compile the `ngfactory` files too (probably because they were generated in the same folder as sources).

My question is: **Are the ngfactories themselves supposed to be compiled or not? Does it affect the application in any way?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngfactory` files are already the compiled output, so you should not compile them again.

It is best to specify a special directory for the `ngfactory.ts` files.
Put this in your tsconfig.json

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "genDir": "compiled"
}
```

This will tell ngc to put the generated files into a `compiled` folder.

Comment: Good to know! Often `tsconfig.json` is however in the source folder, so configuring `"genDir": "compiled"` would just keep the ngfactories in the source folder (under a subfolder). `"genDir": "../compiled"` would probably work better.

Comment: You're right, your solution is cleaner. I also suggest to add that folder to `.gitignore`

Comment: my ngfactory files are always being recompiled even after first compilation and even though I generate files to a different library.
not sure why it recompile the files... any ideas?